# Tree table checkBox issue UI5

Tags: sapui5, treetable

Got a bug in tree table on scroll selected check box position changed

**Before scroll**

[image]

**After Scroll Down**

[image]

Comment: Might have something to do with the behavior mentioned in this [recent commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/b8a0faf62e0a83b5291f2cdb1d33749527927496). Try to reload the app with the UI5 resources from `https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js` to see if the apparent bug is fixed in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

In Tree table, once the HTML is render it will not changed. If you have observe, after table scroll also the generated HTML ID's by UI5 will be same.

So you need to use two way data binding model with a property bind to the checkbox, which will tell the checkbox status ie checked/unchecked.

Means backend data should have a property which is bind to the checkbox `selected` property, so that when ever you select the checkbox the corresponding property will be changed (true/false) and on scrolling also the it will maintain the `selected` property.